# I face this error with my react-native project

Tags: react-native

error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `assert` from `path to my project\node_modules\@jest\console\build\BufferedConsole.js`: Module `assert` does not exist in the Haste module map

I have tried to uninstall npm and reinstall it Again but this was useless

Could you advice why this happens and how could I solve this issue ?

Jest in package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "rn-nodeify": "^10.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

the error in metro bundler is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJvcT.png

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the dependency is missing. First check if your `package.json` has the `jest` library. If everything looks correct, I'd suggest

1. Try removing the cache

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

2. Delete your `node_modules` folder and

```
npm install
```

3. If none works, it could be `babel` issue (but not likely), try

```
npm add @babel/runtime
```

If that still doesn't work, I'd have to ask you to share more code. It's hard to guess what's causing the error without any context.

Comment: Thanks for support I've tried these steps but unfortunately still doesn't work, could you check again I have updated the question and if you need any extra code clarification kindly update me

Comment: Thanks for more info. The error message suggests it might have something to do with https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968 - Have you tried those?

Comment: It looks like this bug is known issue that the cause hasn't been found. You could also try fixing it using xcode https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968#issuecomment-391681549 - but if none of them works, I would suggest walking back your commit history and see which branch caused the error

Comment: Thanks for your support will try :) :)

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: Assert is an in-built package, so it can't be installed from npm. The npm package assert is for browsers